# installing gcc on vista

Tags: gcc, installation

I downloaded gcc 4.4.0 and unzipped it to C:\Program Files\gcc

forgive me for being a novice, but...now what?  I read the install readme file but it's over my head.  how do i get it to work?

Comment: This should be posted on Super User.

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would just [start with cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in the first place. If you do, most of the Unix/Linux/BSD faq's and tutorials will "just work".

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to gcc and want to start using it on Windows, I *highly* recommend the [MinGW GUI installer](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite).

Answer (score 0):

You will edit the environment variable "PATH" to include C:\Program Files\gcc\bin.

[image]
<sub>(source: [justrealized.com](http://i.justrealized.com/media/2008/04/editing-system-environment-variables.jpg))</sub>

Then you can use gcc just like in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Install, you can install Dev C++, which is actually MinGW  with GUI. Dev C++ can probably be clubbed wth cygwin too though I havn't tried it out ever.

Even if the name says C++ in Dev C++, don't worry. I have tried and it does compile C programs as well. I am recommending Dev C++ because most people on Windows have a habit of using GUI for everything in contrast to be people from *nix background.

You can download it [from here](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html)

It also includes GDB which is the debugger you can use. If you are don't know how to use gdb [this tutorial](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/) can come handy.

---

Another aspect of Dev C++ is that it's development has probably ceased as no new versions have been released since Feb,2005 which is more than 4 years. People still use Dev C++ as it does it's job right. The latest version has GCC 3.4.2 bundled with it.

If you are interested in running the most latest or using newer versions of gcc, then you should try out [wxDev C++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/) is an extension of Dev C++. The latest RC was made available somewhere in 1 yr back. It even has in built CVS support

---

Now since you require GCC 4.4.0 , it is [available on MinGW site](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/GCC%20Version%204/Current%20Release_%20gcc-4.4.0/gcc-full-4.4.0-mingw32-bin-2.tar.lzma?use_mirror=biznetnetworks). Try to replace the older gcc dll in Dev C++/wxDev C++ with the newer one from this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do C/C++ programming for fun, Mingw is the simpler way to go about it. You'll also need some libraries to get you started.

Try: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

It's a Mingw distribution based on GCC 4.3.3

It also contains: binutils, boost (with compiled headers), SDL, libbzip, libjpeg, libvorbis, freetype, and many other libraries.

EDIT: I'm not sure if any of the precompiled stuff will work on Vista. I've only tried it on WinXP.